# Jenkins stop all running/pending builds of a job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Using the following code I'm able to stop a running build of a job:

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Deploy")
    .getAllJobs().each { job ->
        job.getBuilds().each { build ->
            build.finish(
                hudson.model.Result.ABORTED,
                new java.io.IOException("Aborting build")
            );                
        }
    }
```

However if there are multiple running builds, or a running one and pending one, I get:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.persistence.IteratorHack$Itr.next(IteratorHack.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor704.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2029)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2015)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2056)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2030)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2015)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2068)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Tried to wrap some code blocks with `try-catch`, but I can't overcome this error. Works fine when only one build is running and stopped.
Not a groovy expert and can't seem to detect the subtle bug here with this opaque exception.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occured probably due to Jenkins discarding the oldest build thus making the 
`NoSuchElementException` error. A simple solution would be:

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Deploy")
    .getAllJobs().each { job ->
        job.getBuilds().findAll{ _job -> _job.isBuilding() }.each { build ->
            build.finish(
                hudson.model.Result.ABORTED,
                new java.io.IOException("Aborting build")
            );                
        }
    }
```